# how to use java parallel stream instead of executorThreadsPool?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I want to write a test that execute many parallel calls to my API.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        final int numOfUsers = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfUsers; i++) {
            executor.execute(() -> {
                final Device device1 = getFirstDevice();
                final ResponseDto responseDto = devicesServiceLocal.acquireDevice(device1.uuid, 4738);
                if (responseDto.status == Status.SUCCESS)
                {
                    successCount.incrementAndGet();
                }
            });
        }
```

I know I can do it using executorThreadsPool, like this:

```
devicesList.parallelStream()
           .map(device -> do something)
```

I could have created it with java8 parallel stream:

How can i do it on one device?

meaning I want few calls to acquire the same device.

something like this:

```
{{device}}.parallelStream().execute(myAction).times(10)
```

Comment: You don’t need to use a stream for everything. Mind the alternative to your code: `Collections.<Runnable>nCopies(numOfUsers, ()->{/* your code */}).forEach(executor::execute);` or similar constructs…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can, but...

You would think

```
Stream.generate(() -> device)
      .limit(10)
      .parallel()
      .forEach(device -> device.execute());
```

should do the job. But NO, because reason (I really do not know why, no clue). 
If I let `device.execute()` wait a second and then let it print something. The stream prints 10 times every second something. So it isn't at all parallel, not what you want.

Google is my friend and I found a lot of articles that warn against parallelStream. But my eye fell on http://blog.jooq.org/2014/06/13/java-8-friday-10-subtle-mistakes-when-using-the-streams-api/ number 8 and 9. 8 was saying if it is backed by a collection you'll have to sort it and it will magically work so:

```
Stream.generate(() -> device)
      .limit(10)
      .sorted((a,b)->0) // Sort it (kind of), what??
      .parallel()
      .forEach(device -> device.execute());
```

And now it prints after one second 8 times and after an other second 2 times something. I have 8 cores so that is what we (kind of) expect.

I used `.forEach()` in my stream, but at first I was (like your example) using `.map()`. `.map()` didn't print a thing: the stream was never consumed (see 9 in the linked article).

So, beware working with streams and especially parallel ones. You have to be sure you're stream is consumed, it is finite (`.limit()`), it is working parallel, etc. Streams are weird, I suggest keeping your working solution.

Note: if `device.execute()` is a blocking operation (IO, networking...) you will never have more than your number of cores (in my case 8) tasks that will be executed at the same time.

**Update (thanks to [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)):**

Holger gave an elegant alternative:

```
IntStream.range(0,10)
      .parallel()
      .mapToObject(i -> getDevice())
      .forEach(device -> device.execute());

// Or shorter:
IntStream.range(0,10)
      .parallel()
      .forEach(i -> getDevice().execute());
```

which is just like a parallel for-loop (and it works).

Comment: The `sorted` is an interesting hack (you could use `Comparator.nullsFirst(null)` instead of `(a,b)->0`), but you’re better off using a clean `IntStream.range(0, 10).parallel().mapToObj(i -> create()).forEach(device -> device.execute());`…