# Loops asynchronous using Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have nested loops. I understand there is no way of decreasing the time taken by the nested loops to complete. But how can we complete the loop faster using multithreading or executor Service.

For Example:

```
for(String str : ListA){
  for(String str1 : ListB){
     for(String str2 : ListC){
         //do Something
     }
  }
}
```

So i understand it takes M*N*P(where M,N,P are the size of the List) times to complete the loop. But how can i make use of multithreading here and complete the loop faster by performing asynchronous jobs. I want to use Executor Service as i am using java 7 (Parallel Streams cannot be used).

I tried :

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for(String str : ListA){
     executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      for(String str1 : ListB){
        for(String str2 : ListC){
         //do Something
        }
      }
    } });
 }
```

But i believe in the above process is starting the thread 10 times but executing the same thing 10 times and thats not how looping works. Can anyb one please suggest me how to complete this looping using multithreading executor Service in Java please?

Comment: Submit your //do Something logic to executor pool.

Comment: Can you please provide a shot example on what you mean please ? @karthikdivi

Comment: Ideal use case for parallel stream, refer doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html  or the same is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402481/how-to-use-java-parallel-stream-instead-of-executorthreadspool

Comment: @sanojmathew I am using Java7 as said in the question. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

Loop is fast enough you don't have to optimize it. The actual code what you are performing in //do something can be a problem it if has blocking behaviour. In that case you can do the following

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

List<String> level1 = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
List<String> level2 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
List<String> level3 = Arrays.asList("x", "y", "z");
for(String l1 : level1){
  for(String l2 : level2){
     for(String l3 : level3){
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                get("http://foo.com/"+l1+"/"+l2+"/"+l3);
            }
        });
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the result of the //do something is not interdependent on other iterations of the loop

Comment: @SteelToe the result needs to be saved in a list. But i have an issue here. Can any one please suggest. I need to save the result of dosomething in a JSONObject. I have created the JSONOBject jsonObject=null; and try to use it in "doSomething" but it says to make JSONOBject as final and after making that final i am getting an error: "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable jsonObject defined in an enclosing scope"

Comment: @karthikdivi thanks for the suggestion. But can you please suggest me something here. When i implement in the way you have suggested, I need to save the result of dosomething in a JSONObject. I have created the JSONOBject jsonObject=null; and try to use it in "doSomething" but it says to make JSONOBject as final and after making that final i am getting an error: "Cannot refer to the non-final local variable jsonObject defined in an enclosing scope"

Comment: If you want to make //do Something in parallel then that piece of code should be isolated otherwise you will run into issues. Can you please provide more code and try to mention the exact problem you are trying to solve? Then i can think of the right way of using parallelism.

Comment: Basically i want to make API calls based on three strings (str, str1, str2). So instead of looping it i want to make the loop execute paralelly in java 7. Lets say str2 has 3 values {a,b,c} and str2 has 4 values{1,2,3,4} and str has two values:{x,y} then i want to make all combinations here. lets say if str has x, and str2 has 1 for the intial looping now i want to make these calls parallel like: http:apicall/x/1/a,http:apicall/x/1/b,http:apicall/x/1/c. So basically here i would like to start three threads and complete the inner most loop in one go parallely to complete it. @karthikdivi

Comment: I see that the http hits are independent i.e the response of one not required for another. I have updated my answer that should work for your case, you need to add implementation for get method.